# How can we force the military to kill civilians?

Tags: pc, dwarf-fortress

Given that I want a squad to kill my own dwarves, how would I go about accomplishing this?

The <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> screen does not allow me to select any dwarves (other than the outpost liaison) for slaughter:

[image: Screencap]

I understand that there are other ways to kill dwarves, but I would prefer to use the military :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. And it would be very bad if you did. See http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Loyalty_cascade#Loyalty_cascade

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to have your military attack non manic dwarves. Really, this is a good thing (except in the case of nobles and children) because dwarves make friends and have families so killing one usually results in their friends and family rioting causing mass !!FUN!!. There are lots of other ways to dispose of unwanted civilians including (but not limited to) magma, forgotten beasts, danger rooms, swimming training, !!SCIENCE!!, etc. For more information, check the wiki under !!FUN!!.

Comment: **!!SCIENCE!!** means ?

Comment: Check this out: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/!!SCIENCE!!

Comment: The above link's malformed. But you'll get to the right page just by adding the missing two '!'s to the URL.